# Reference request for representation theory about functors

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, functors

Let $\Lambda$ be an artin algebra. We deonte by $mod \Lambda$ the category of all finitely generated $\Lambda$-modules. $\mathcal{Y}$ is a subcategory of $mod \Lambda$ closed under extensions and summands.

I have seen the following :"If $Ext_{\Lambda} ^1(C,-) |_{\mathcal{Y}}$ is a finitely generated functor from $\mathcal{Y}$ to abelian groups, since $\mathcal{Y}$ is closed under summands it follows that  $Ext_{\Lambda} ^1(C,-) |_{\mathcal{Y}}$ has a projective cover $Hom_{\Lambda}(Y,-) \stackrel{\varphi}{\longrightarrow} Ext_{\Lambda} ^1(C,-) |_{\mathcal{Y}}$. Let $0 \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} C \rightarrow 0$ be $\varphi(1_X)$. Then $f:X \rightarrow C$ is right minimal is an immediate consequence of the fact that $\varphi: Hom_{\Lambda}(Y,-) \rightarrow Ext_{\Lambda} ^1(C,-) |_{\mathcal{Y}}$ is a projective cover"

I just know finitely generated or projective cover for modules, could anyone provide me some references about those theories about functors? Or how to get that $f: X \rightarrow C$ is right minimal?

Comment: there seems to be no good reference for such things in the literature yet. You can look at Auslanders first papers about artin algebras, where he uses the more general functor approach. There you should certanly find such things.

Comment: To be precise, please read the paper ' A functorial approach to representation theory'  by Auslander, in particular notice the notion 'simple functor', 'radical of a functor', etc.